# visual studio not responding on build

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build

I have a strange problem with VS2008.  My solution has 8 projects (all c#) and hangs VS when I build.  The task manager says "not responding" and the process takes 100% of one of my cores, and the memory usage gradually climbs.  Eventualy the IDE responds again, builds and deploys.  The hang time seems to grow longer and longer each time I build, but then when I reboot there is no hang and it goes right to the build.  Anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea, but what happens when you run MSBuild on the command line with your solution?  Does it hang?  If so, run it again with full verbosity and see where it hangs.

Comment: MSBuild does not hang.  It must be some memory leak in the IDE or something.  This is an acceptable work around for now...thanks.

Comment: Totally bummed to hear it.  Also check to see if uninstalling some of our VS plugins (if you have 'em) changes anything.

Answer (score 4):

You can run Visual Studio in a way as to log what is happening.
Open your IDE directory, find devenv.exe.config, and add this line:

```
  <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
            <listeners>
               <add name="myListener" 
type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener, System version=1.0.3300.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
initializeData="c:\myListener.log" />
               <remove name="Default" />
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
```

This should create a log file on you c drive (once you restart visual studio).
Be sure to backup your existing devenv.exe.config first.

View the log and hopefully you will see which actions are causing it to take so long.

Comment: When I add this to the devenv.exe.config file, I get a lot of package load failures and errors.  Is there a typo in it or could I be putting it in the wrong section?

Comment: The configuration here worked for VS 2010.
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2010/05/23/how-to-enable-visual-studio-2010-log.aspx

Comment: I tried this with VS2008 and it did not work. It would not load startup packages and threw errors when trying to build.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It seems that my antivirus (avast) was detecting the compiled program as malware and blocking it. When I tried to build with avast's "File System Shield" turned off, I had no problem.

Try to turn "File System Shield" off, or even better disable the specific folder through "File System Shield" options.

Answer (score 1):

By default Visual Studio build only uses 1 core!

To get the build process to use all cores use MSBuild!

Have a read of this excellent blog entry on [Speeding Up Visual Studio Builds](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/197663/Speed-up-Visual-Studio-Builds)